# Could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++, dll

i'm having trouble reading from a text file in C++, so basically I want to read the text file on "cmd" using this code, however, an error pops up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace::std;
int main()
{
    string line_;
    ifstream file("Seminario.txt");
    if(file.is_open()){
        while(getline(file, line_)){
            cout << line_ << endl;
        }

        file.close();
    }
    else{
        cout << "File is not open" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I compile it, I get no errors, however, when I run a.exe, a window pops up saying:

> The procedure entry point
>   _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Progra\a.exe.

How can I fix this?

Comment: not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you build the executable?

Comment: It looks like you built this as a dll. Try building it as an executable.

Comment: @Aumnayan how do I explicitly build it as a .exe? I thought that when I compiled it as "g++ (name.cpp)" it automatically formed an executable file

Comment: @NeilButterworth  
I built it using Mingw compiler, that means g++ helloworld.cpp so it defaults into building an "a.exe"

Comment: @Lithorz My Apologies. I read the output and simply stated where I would start looking for the problem. Looking at this further, you have a problem with a dll that the application uses. Responses to similar problems seam to indicate that this usually steams from an incorrect .dll version. Do you get the same problem with a simple hello world program? If not, you can start ironing out which dll has a problem by evaluating the differences between the two application... And no, I'm not sure how to accomplish that off the top of my head.

Comment: @Lithorz As FYI: I also can't reproduce the problem. I am leaning towards the problem existing in your build tools.